# Need Timer circuit with Multiple Functions

Tags: timer, display

[image: a board with some SMDs][image: flip side showing UI elements listed below]
Need a prototype following these requirements:

1. 3 MICRO SWITCHES (Push to close)
2. 1 LED
3. BUZZER
4. RESISTORS etc
5. 2 digits 7 SEGMENT DISPLAY
6. 1 DUAL TIMER IC (8 PINS)
7. 25C08 EEPROM

STATES:

1. MAX TIME 10 SECS
2. SWITCH 1 TO START COUNTING
3. SWITCH 2 TO SELECT TIME
   SWITCH 3 TO INCREASE TIME

SIZE: 18mm x 62mm

To keep cost low, I don't want to use a microcontroller. It should be with timer IC and some EEPROM.

Comment: Cheapest way to implement it is probably with an MCU. Anyway, your question is way too broad and have the characteristics of “design it for me”, which we don’t do here. Instead, try to implement it and ask a _specific answerable_ question if you are stuck.

Comment: There is no question, just specs of what you want and ruling out the simplest way of using MCU for it, so it makes little sense.

Comment: Here they used ATTiny26 Microcontroller which is bit costly

Comment: There are cheaper MCUs but tiny would be a very good fit here.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to use Microcontroller to eleminate cost.

Usually devices like this would use STM8 or a similar micro that costs like $0.30 each, although STM8 prices are highly variable at the moment it seems. You'll absolutely not make anything cheaper with a "timer IC and EEPROM". What is your volume? That determines most of it.

Anyway, if you're making less than a couple thousand of those things, your time is so expensive that choosing a $0.30 or a $1.30 MCU doesn't matter whatsoever, since your own overheads will swamp the BOM cost.

What you've described sounds like something you'd give to a contractor to work on. Questions here should pertain to designs you're intending to work on. Since you claim that an MCU makes it "expensive", where in reality it'd be doing the very opposite, means that you haven't even looked on DigiKey at MCU prices... That'd be a good start. Things have changed over the last few decades :)

> Here they used ATTiny26 Microcontroller which is bit costly

Um, what?

- [ATTINY26A-XURCT-ND](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/microchip-technology/ATTINY261A-XUR/2357376) sells for $0.50 each qty 100

The alteratives cost in the same ballpark - the price differences only matter in high quantities - say tens of thousands or more. Otherwise your time spent looking for a chip costs more than the price differences in chips will.

- [STM8S003F3P6TR](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/stmicroelectronics/STM8S003F3P6TR/4357536) sells for $0.60 each qty 100
- [CH32V003F4U6](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Microcontroller-Units-MCUs-MPUs-SOCs_WCH-Jiangsu-Qin-Heng-CH32V003F4U6_C5299908.html) sells for $0.18 each qty 150

> What components /ICs can be used as they have already used this ATTiny26 but I don't want to use that.

Why don't you want to use that? There's nothing wrong with it. Just go on DigiKey, look for microcontrollers, set your target quantity, filter on in-stock, non-marketplace items, and sort by price, ascending. That's all. But note that not all parts are available on DigiKey. There are some excellent Chinese parts that DigiKey doesn't sell, like the CH32V003 RISC-V chip.

> ATTiny26 Microcontroller [...] needs libraries to put in to

That's a good thing. Less code for you to write, with your time being most expensive :)

> And one more challenging thing is the size of this PCB which is 18mm x 62mm

Not much of a challenge. For low-end MCUs, IC package costs influence the price a lot, and the smaller the package, the cheaper it usually is. So that's far from a challenge: it's a good thing. You'd have some trouble if you wanted a big package like DIP instead!

---

To get an idea of how much something with similar functionality may be selling for, see [this 4.5-digit digital voltmeter](https://www.ebay.com/itm/222362829217). $8 each plus $3 shipping. Uses STM8.